# How do I get a python program to run instead of opening in Notepad?

Tags: python, notepad

I am having some trouble with opening a .py file. I have a program that calls this .py file (i.e. pathname/example.py file.txt), but instead of running the python program, it opens it in Notepad. How to I get it to run?

The program itself takes in a file, and creates an output that is more readable.

Edit: The operating system is Windows 7. And the file that is calling the python is a .bat file.

Edit 2: It looks like I had to reinstall python for some reason... but it looks like it is finally working. Why reinstalling never comes to mind in the first place... And then I had to change how the file extention was opened. Thanks guys

Answer (score 9):

This happened because most probably you have set notepad as the default program to open a .py file. Go to default programs app in windows. Select choose app by extension. Here search for .py files. Change the option from notepad to python. This should solve your problem.

Comment: python option not coming

Comment: Do you have python installed with its default ide IDLE installed properly?

Answer (score 3):

okay.
1) i tried turning it off and on again. 
2) i uninstalled and reinstalled python

still no joy.  and then!

in windows explorer there's an open with option that sets the default program that windows is pointed toward if you click on the filename or enter it on the command line.  change that from notepad or whatever it is if it's not python.  change it to python.  then presto. no problem-o.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it from the command line. 
http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run the program like this?

```
   /dirdir/MyPythonScript.py
```

try the following instead

```
   python /dirdir/MyPythonScript.py
```

Comment: I've tried this, but get the error " 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command." I do have python set in the PATH for windows.

Comment: can you run the script using python myscript.py outside the program(ie the cmd prompt)?

Comment: Which program(or language) are u using to try to launch the python script?

Comment: I suppose that i'm trying to run it from windows. I can run it from the cmd prompt just fine.